Segmentation fault ('core dumped') - Summit XL navigation
When I execute this node I receive the error mentioned in the title and I had already tried many things but anything worked, what can I do?
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf2_ros/static_transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <tf2_ros/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/common/distances.h>
#include <pcl/common/common.h>
#include <pcl/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h>
//#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>
#include <costmap_2d/costmap_2d_ros.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <pcl/search/impl/kdtree.hpp>
#include <pcl/kdtree/impl/kdtree_flann.hpp>
#include <tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h>
#include <tf2_ros/transform_listener.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include <tf2_ros/message_filter.h>
#include <tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>

ros::Publisher pub;
nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid costmap_p;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> nubeDePuntos_p;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> output_cloud;
// output_cloud.width = 0;  // Inicializa el ancho como 0
// output_cloud.height = 0; // Inicializa la altura como 0
// output_cloud.points.resize(0); // Inicializa el vector de puntos con tamano 0
nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid dev;
costmap_2d::Costmap2D tf_costmap;



// Funcion para convertir un nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid a un costmap_2d::Costmap2D
costmap_2d::Costmap2D convertirACostmap2D( nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid& occupancy_grid, tf::TransformListener& tf) {
    //auto costmap = std::make_shared<costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS>("mi_costmap", tf);
    costmap_2d::Costmap2D costmap_data(occupancy_grid.info.width, occupancy_grid.info.height, 
                                        occupancy_grid.info.resolution, 
                                        occupancy_grid.info.origin.position.x, 
                                        occupancy_grid.info.origin.position.y);

    // Copiar los datos de ocupacion del mensaje OccupancyGrid al Costmap2D
    for(unsigned int x = 0; x < occupancy_grid.info.width; ++x) {
        for(unsigned int y = 0; y < occupancy_grid.info.height; ++y) {
            int8_t occupancy_value = occupancy_grid.data[x + y * occupancy_grid.info.width];
            unsigned char cost = costmap_2d::FREE_SPACE; // Por defecto, se considera celda libre

            if (occupancy_value == 100) {
                cost = costmap_2d::LETHAL_OBSTACLE; // Si es 100, se considera un obstaculo letal
            } else if (occupancy_value > 0) {
                cost = costmap_2d::INSCRIBED_INFLATED_OBSTACLE; // Si es mayor que 0, se considera un obstaculo inscrito
            }

            costmap_data.setCost(x, y, cost);
        }
    }

    //costmap->updateMap();
    return costmap_data;
}



nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid filterSlopesFn (  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> input_cloud,
                                          nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid costmap_data )
{
    int i = 0;
    //pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> output_cloud;
    if(input_cloud.size()>0){
        using namespace pcl;
        //pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud (const pcl::PointCloud< PointT > &cloud_in, pcl::PointCloud< PointT > &cloud_out, Indices &index)
        // Parametro de umbral de inclinacion (ajusta segun sea necesario)
        double slope_threshold = 0.1;
        output_cloud.clear();
        std::cout<<input_cloud.size()<<std::endl;
        ROS_INFO("publi");
        pub.publish(costmap_data);

        // Construir un kdtree para buscar vecinos
        pcl::KdTreeFLANN<pcl::PointXYZ> kdtree;
        kdtree.setInputCloud(input_cloud.makeShared());
        
        costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros;
        tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster broadcaster;         
        tf2::Quaternion quaternion_combined;

        // output_cloud.height = input_cloud.height;
        // output_cloud.width = input_cloud.width;
        // output_cloud.resize(100);
        // Iterar a traves de los puntos de la nube
        //#pragma omp parallel for
        for (auto& point : input_cloud.points)
        {
            ros::NodeHandle nh;
            // Convertir pcl::PointCloud a sensor_msgs::PointCloud2

            quaternion_combined.setRPY(M_PI / 2, 0, M_PI / 2); // Roll (X), Pitch (Y), Yaw (Z)

            // Crear un mensaje de transformacion para la nueva transformacion estatica
            geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transform_msg;
            transform_msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
            transform_msg.header.frame_id = "robot_base_link"; // Marco de referencia origen
            transform_msg.child_frame_id = "frame_transformado"; // Nuevo marco de referencia
            transform_msg.transform.translation.x = 0.0; // Ajusta segun sea necesario
            transform_msg.transform.translation.y = 0.0; // Ajusta segun sea necesario
            transform_msg.transform.translation.z = 0.0; // Ajusta segun sea necesario
            transform_msg.transform.rotation.x = quaternion_combined.x(); // Ajusta segun sea necesario
            transform_msg.transform.rotation.y = quaternion_combined.y(); // Ajusta segun sea necesario
            transform_msg.transform.rotation.z = quaternion_combined.z(); // Ajusta segun sea necesario
            transform_msg.transform.rotation.w = quaternion_combined.w(); // Ajusta segun sea necesario

            // Publicar la transformacion estatica
            broadcaster.sendTransform(transform_msg);

            sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud_msg;
            pcl::toROSMsg(output_cloud, cloud_msg);

            // Configurar el marco de referencia
            cloud_msg.header.frame_id = "frame_transformado"; // Reemplaza "base_link" con el marco de referencia adecuado

            // Publicar el mensaje
            ros::Publisher filtered_cloud_pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("/robot/filtered_point_cloud", 1);
            filtered_cloud_pub.publish(cloud_msg);
            // ros::Publisher filtered_cloud_pub = nh.advertise<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>>("/robot/filtered_point_cloud", 1);
            // filtered_cloud_pub.publish(output_cloud);

            i = i+1;
            if(pcl_isfinite(point.x) && pcl_isfinite(point.y) && pcl_isfinite(point.z)){
                //ROS_INFO("hola");
                // Buscar vecinos del punto
                std::vector<int> point_indices;
                std::vector<float> point_distances;
                kdtree.radiusSearch(point, 1.0, point_indices, point_distances);
                //std::cout<< i <<std::endl;
                // Verificar si hay vecinos suficientes para calcular la pendiente
                if (point_indices.size() >= 3 && point_indices[1] < input_cloud.points.size())
                {
                    // Calcular la inclinacion local (pendiente en el eje Z)
                    double slope = (input_cloud.points[point_indices[1]].z - point.z) /
                                sqrt(pow(input_cloud.points[point_indices[1]].x - point.x, 2) +
                                        pow(input_cloud.points[point_indices[1]].y - point.y, 2));

                    // Agregar el punto al nuevo cloud si cumple con los criterios
                    if (fabs(slope) < slope_threshold)
                    {
                        //std::cout << "Type of point: " << typeid(point).name() << std::endl;
                        //std::cout<<point<<std::endl;
                        //ROS_INFO("hola");
                        // try {
                        //     output_cloud.points.push_back(point);
                        // } catch (const std::exception& e) {
                        //     std::cerr << "Exception caught: " << e.what() << std::endl;
                        // }
                        output_cloud.push_back(point);
                        //std::cout<<"Tamano de nube:" << output_cloud.size()<<std::endl;
                    }
                }
                
                if(i == input_cloud.size() - 1){
                    //std::cout<<"Tamano de nube:" << output_cloud.size()<<std::endl;
                    // for (auto& point : output_cloud.points)
                    // {
                    //     std::cout << "X: " << point.x << ", Y: " << point.y << ", Z: " << point.z << std::endl;
                    // }
                }
            }


        }
    }


    // ros::NodeHandle nh;
    // ros::Publisher filtered_cloud_pub = nh.advertise<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>>("/robot/filtered_point_cloud", 1);
    // filtered_cloud_pub.publish(output_cloud);

    for ( auto& point : output_cloud.points) {
        //ROS_INFO("si");
        double costmap_x = point.x;
        double costmap_y = point.y;
        // ROS_INFO("x: %lf, y: %lf, z: %lf ", costmap_x, costmap_y);
        
        // *Modificar costos en el costmap local*
        // Supongamos que costmap es un objeto costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS ya inicializado
        //for ( auto& point : output_cloud.points) {
            
            //costmap_data.data[point.y * costmap_data.info.width + point.x] = costmap_2d::FREE_SPACE;

        int width = costmap_data.info.width;
        int height = costmap_data.info.height;

        // Calcula el indice correspondiente a la posicion (costmap_x, costmap_y)
        int index = costmap_x + costmap_y * width;

        // Asegurate de que el indice este dentro de los limites del array de datos
        tf::TransformListener tf_listener;
        //tf::TransformListener& tf_listener;
        //costmap_2d::Costmap2D tf_costmap;
        if(pcl_isfinite(point.x) && pcl_isfinite(point.y) && pcl_isfinite(point.z)){
            tf_costmap = convertirACostmap2D(costmap_data, tf_listener);
            // Accede y modifica el valor del mapa en la posicion (costmap_x, costmap_y)
            tf_costmap.setCost(costmap_x, costmap_y, 0);
            //std::cout<<tf_costmap<<std::endl;
            //costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS costmap_final("costmapfinal", tf_listener);
        }

    }
        // Copiar los datos del costmap a los datos de la grid de ocupacion
        costmap_data.data.resize(tf_costmap.getSizeInCellsX() * tf_costmap.getSizeInCellsY());
        for (unsigned int y = 0; y < tf_costmap.getSizeInCellsY(); ++y) {
            for (unsigned int x = 0; x < tf_costmap.getSizeInCellsX(); ++x) {
                ROS_INFO("paso");
                unsigned int costmap_index = tf_costmap.getIndex(x, y);
                unsigned char cost = tf_costmap.getCost(x, y);
                if (cost == costmap_2d::LETHAL_OBSTACLE) {
                    costmap_data.data[y * tf_costmap.getSizeInCellsX() + x] = 100; // Celda ocupada
                } else if (cost == costmap_2d::INSCRIBED_INFLATED_OBSTACLE ||
                        cost == costmap_2d::NO_INFORMATION) {
                    costmap_data.data[y * tf_costmap.getSizeInCellsX() + x] = 100; // Celda desconocida
                } else {
                    costmap_data.data[y * tf_costmap.getSizeInCellsX() + x] = 100; // Celda libre
                }
            }
        }
        ROS_INFO("no");
        pub.publish(dev);

    
    //return costmap_data;
    
}

nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid filterSlopes(  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> input_cloud,
                                            nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid costmap_data )
{
    //ros::Rate;

    ros::spinOnce();

    // Filtro de muestreo para reducir la densidad
    pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZ> sor;
    sor.setInputCloud(input_cloud.makeShared());
    sor.setLeafSize(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);  // Ajusta el tamano del voxel segun tus necesidades
    sor.filter(input_cloud);
    return filterSlopesFn(input_cloud, costmap_data);
}

void cloudCallback(  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> dato1)
{
    // Procesar la nube de puntos aqui para distinguir pendientes
    //pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr filtered_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

    // Filtrar pendientes
    nubeDePuntos_p = dato1;

    // Publicar la nube de puntos filtrada si es necesario
    filterSlopes(nubeDePuntos_p, costmap_p);
}

void costmapCallback(nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid dato2)
{
    // Procesar la nube de puntos aqui para distinguir pendientes
    // pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr filtered_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

    // Filtrar pendientes
    // costmap_p = boost::make_shared<nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid>(*dato2);
    costmap_p = dato2;

    // Publicar la nube de puntos filtrada si es necesario
    dev = filterSlopes(nubeDePuntos_p, costmap_p);
    //std::cout<<dev<<std::endl;
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    //pub = nh.advertise<nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid>("/robot/move_base/local_costmap/costmap", 1000);
    //ROS_INFO("publi");
    // pub.publish(dev);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "slope_filter_node");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    //costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS tf_costmap("tf_costmap", tf);

    // Sustituye "point_cloud_topic" con el nombre del topico de la nube de puntos de tu camara RGBD
    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe<const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>>("/robot/front_rgbd_camera/depth/points", 1000, cloudCallback);
    ros::Subscriber sub2 = nh.subscribe<nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid>("/robot/move_base/local_costmap/costmap", 1000, costmapCallback);
    
    pub = nh.advertise<nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid>("/robot/nube_filtrada", 1000);
    pub.publish(dev);

    // Sustituye "filtered_point_cloud_topic" con el nombre del nuevo topico para la nube de puntos filtrada
    // pub = nh.advertise<nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid>("/robot/nube_filtrada", 1);
    
    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
